# How to use a service defined in another module than the controller calling it?

Tags: angularjs

I have a module with a service defined:

```
var ngError = angular.module('ngError', []);

ngError.service('ErrorService', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.displayErrors = function(errors) {
        alert(errors);
    }
}]);
```

Then I have another module:

```
var ngLogin = angular.module('ngLogin', ['ngError']);
```

Which has a controller that attempts to use the first service defined on `ngError`:

```
ngLogin.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', 'LoginService', 'ErrorService', function($scope, LoginService, ErrorService) {
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.user.id = 0;
    $scope.user.token = '';

    $scope.login = function(callback) {
     LoginService.login($scope.user.username, $scope.user.password, function(token) {
        $scope.setToken(token);
        $scope.$apply();
        if (typeof callback === 'function') {
            callback(callback);
        }
     }, function(errors) {
        ErrorService.displayErrors(errors);
     });
};
}]);
```

But some reason this is throwing the following error:

```
Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- ErrorService
```

Comment: By the way, never prefix your own services with ng when you use angular. The reason angular prefixes his services/directives/... with ng is to make sure your app won't break the day they create a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `$scope` within a service. Change the service as follows and it will work:

```
var ngError = angular.module('ngError', []);

ngError.service('ErrorService', [function() {
    this.displayErrors = function(errors) {
        alert(errors);
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this , working best for me

```js
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);
app.service('MyService', function () {
    var property = 'First';
    this.myFunc = function (x) {
        return x*5;
    }
});

//
controller 2 under second app module


var app = angular.module('AnotherApp',[]);
app.controller("AnotherAppCtrl", function($scope,MyService) {
 $scope.value = MyService.myFunc(4);
});
```